# Rails 500 Internal Server Error jquery.js:8417 when setting up endless scroll Kaminari Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, infinite-scroll, kaminari

I'm new to web development and have started building a rails app where I would like to implement endless scrolling.  To do this I set up the Kaminari pagination gem in my app and that is working fine.  To do the endless scrolling piece I followed Railscast 114 (revised).  Of course, it isn't working.  When I load the page, it loads fine and after a couple seconds.

**error in the Chrome web dev console:**

```
GET http://localhost:3000/home?page=2&_=8917348102384 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js:8417

If I expand this error I see the following:

send jquery.js:8417

jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7969

jQuery.(anonymous function) jquery.js:7496

jQuery.extend.getScript jquery.js:7509

(anonymous function) recent.js:10

jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3064

elemData.handle.eventHandle jquery.js:2682

jQuery.event.trigger jquery.js:2947

(anonymous function) jquery.js:3605

jQuery.extend.each jquery.js:612

jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery.js:242

jQuery.fn.extend.trigger jquery.js:3604

jQuery.fn.(anonymous function) jquery.js:3658

(anonymous function) recent.js:13

fire jquery.js:975

self.fireWith jquery.js:1083

jQuery.extend.ready jquery.js:407

DOMContentLoaded jquery.js:84
```

The URL in the error is the URL for the next set of images and if clicked will take me to them.  From that page the console will display the same error with a new URL to the next set of images etc.  So, it seems like it is half working.  I've been stuck on this for hours and hours.  Let me know if posting any of my code would be helpful.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: the jQuery error trace is not really helpful. Post the log output from your rails server instead :)

Most likely you just built your URL wrong in your javascript code: `http://localhost:3000/home?page=2&=8917348102384`does not look right

Comment: Can't beleive I didn't check server log, but still don't understand.
Processing by FeedController#home as JS
  Parameters: {"page"=>"2", "_"=>"1353260596605"}
  Rendered feed/home.js.erb (478.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3577ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `recent' for #<#<Class:0x007fd9842102b8>:0x007fd984018708>):
    1: $('#recent_div').append('<%= j render(recent) %>');
    2:   $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j paginate(recent) %>'); 
  app/views/feed/home.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_feed_home_js_erb___4348437972978749170_70286100002500'